# Organizing Simulation Results

Tags: c++

I wrote a queue program based on a checkout simulation taking data from a text file (sim.txt). I got everything to work in my code except for one thing. I want to organize each sim result by numbers.

**sim.txt**

```
2000
0.10
5
15
5
20
10000
0.05
5
15
5
18
2000
0.20
5
20
10
10
2000
0.20
1
5
10
25
20000
0.50
1
2
50
10
```

**Here is an example output**

```
Simulation Results #1

       // result #1 output is here...

Simulation Results #2

       // result #2 output is here...

Simulation Results #3

       // result #3 output is here...

Simulation Results #4

       // result #4 output is here...

Simulation Results #5

       // result #5 output is here...
```

I tried implementing a for loop to achieve this, but it didn't work as expected. This problem occurs for each simulation result.

```
Simulation Results #1
Simulation Results #2
Simulation Results #3
Simulation Results #4
Simulation Results #5

         // result #1 outputs here...
```

**Here is my code to get a better look what I'm doing**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// Input parameters
#define SIMULATION_TIME     0
#define ARRIVAL_RATE        1
#define MIN_SERVICE_TIME    2
#define MAX_SERVICE_TIME    3
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE       4
#define ANGRY_THRESHOLD     5
#define PARAMS_MAX          6
#define FILENAME            "sim.txt"

// Or like this:
// const int SIMULATION_TIME = 0;

// Or make 6 variables:
// double SIMULATION_TIME = 0;

// Counters -- indexes into variable 'counters' below
#define CUSTOMERS_SERVICED  0
#define CUSTOMERS_LEAVING   1
#define AVERAGE_WAIT        2
#define AVERAGE_LINE        3
#define ANGRY_CUSTOMERS     4
#define COUNTERS_MAX        5

// Holds the current simulation parameters
double parameters[PARAMS_MAX];
double counters[COUNTERS_MAX];

// This is an example debug macro you can use to print
// things each time through the loop
#define DEBUGGING_ENABLED 1
#ifdef DEBUGGING_ENABLED
#define DEBUG(x) do { \
        cerr << __FILE__ << ": " << __LINE__ << ": " << x << endl; \
    } while (0)
#else
#define DEBUG(x)
#endif // DEBUGGING_ENABLED

// Return the service interval, between 'min'
// and 'max'.
int randomInt(int min, int max)
{
    return (rand() % (max - min) + min);
}
// Returns TRUE if a customer arrived during this minute
bool randomChance(double prob)
{
    double rv = rand() / (double(RAND_MAX) + 1);
    return (rv < prob);
}

// Read the next simulation from the file.  Return
// TRUE if one could be read, FALSE otherwise (eof).
bool readNextSim(fstream &f, double parameters[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PARAMS_MAX; i++)
    {
        string tmp;
        getline(f, tmp);
        if (f.eof())
            return false;
        // Read in the next parameter
        parameters[i] = atof(tmp.c_str());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout <<"Simulation Results #" << i + 1 << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    cout << "\t Overall simulation time: " << "\t" << parameters[SIMULATION_TIME] << endl;
    cout << "\t Arrival rate: " << "\t\t\t" << parameters[ARRIVAL_RATE] << endl;
    cout << "\t Minimum service time: " << "\t\t" << parameters[MIN_SERVICE_TIME] << endl;
    cout << "\t Maximum service time: " << "\t\t" << parameters[MAX_SERVICE_TIME] << endl;
    cout << "\t Maximum line size: " << "\t\t" << parameters[MAX_LINE_SIZE] << endl;
    cout << "\t Angry threshold: " << "\t\t" << parameters[ANGRY_THRESHOLD] << endl;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    fstream f(FILENAME);

    // Seed the random number generator here
    srand(time(0));

    if (!f.good())
    {
        cout << "Invalid file." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    while (readNextSim(f, parameters))
    {
        // Run the next simulation
        queue<int> line;

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNTERS_MAX; i++)
            counters[i] = 0;

        // or:
        // memset(counters, 0, COUNTERS_MAX * sizeof(double));

        //int customersLeavingLineFull = 0;
        int simTime = 0;
        int currentCustomer = -1;

        // Each time through this loop represents 1 minute passing.
        // There needs to be code to handle everything that can happen
        // in 1 minute:
        //  - Customer arriving (yes/no?)
        //  - Is the current customer finished
        //  - Possibly process the next person in line
        //  - Calculate simulation statistics along the way
        while (simTime++ < parameters[SIMULATION_TIME])
        {
            // One iteration of the loop represents one
            // minute of simulation time.

            // Check to see if a customer arrived
            // (if so, process, also see if the line is full)
            bool arrived = randomChance(parameters[ARRIVAL_RATE]);
            if (arrived)
            {
                // A customer arrived in this minute
                if (currentCustomer == -1)
                {
                    // No customer is currently at the cashier
                    int serviceTime = randomInt(parameters[MIN_SERVICE_TIME],
                                                parameters[MAX_SERVICE_TIME]);

                    currentCustomer = simTime + serviceTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (line.size() == parameters[MAX_LINE_SIZE])
                    {
                        // Count this customer as leaving because the line is too
                        // full
                        counters[CUSTOMERS_LEAVING]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line.push(simTime);
                    }
                }
            }

            counters[AVERAGE_LINE] += line.size();

            // Check to see if the current customer is done
            // at the cashier.  Also check if there is no customer
            // at the cashier (in which the next customer goes to the
            // cashier).
            if (simTime == currentCustomer)
            {
                if (!line.empty())
                {
                    int nextCustomerTimestamp = line.front();
                    int waitingTime = simTime - nextCustomerTimestamp;

                    // We need to include this in the average waiting times
                    if (waitingTime >= parameters[ANGRY_THRESHOLD])
                        counters[ANGRY_CUSTOMERS]++;

                    counters[AVERAGE_WAIT] += waitingTime;

                    // Set currentCustomer to the time when that customer
                    // will be done.  Need to call randomInt().
                    int serviceTime = randomInt(parameters[MIN_SERVICE_TIME],
                                                parameters[MAX_SERVICE_TIME]);

                    // This will give us a timestamp of when the current customer will
                    // be done.
                    currentCustomer = simTime + serviceTime;

                    line.pop();
                    counters[CUSTOMERS_SERVICED]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // The line is empty
                    counters[CUSTOMERS_SERVICED]++;
                    currentCustomer = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        // Print a summary of the simulation:
        // counters
        counters[AVERAGE_WAIT] /= counters[CUSTOMERS_SERVICED];
        counters[AVERAGE_LINE] /= parameters[SIMULATION_TIME];

        cout << endl;
        cout << "\t Customers serviced: " << "\t\t" << counters[CUSTOMERS_SERVICED] << endl;
        cout << "\t Customers leaving: " << "\t\t" << counters[CUSTOMERS_LEAVING] << endl;
        cout << "\t Average time spent in line: " << "\t" << counters[AVERAGE_WAIT] << endl;
        cout << "\t Average line length: " << "\t\t" << counters[AVERAGE_LINE] << endl;
        cout << "\t Angry customers: " << "\t\t" << counters[ANGRY_CUSTOMERS] << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any advice on how to achieve the example output above would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't have curly brackets around your for loop, thus only the first statement gets executed.

Comment: I still get the same problem by adding the curly brackets for the loop

Comment: If I get rid of the for loop, it does give the expected output except that it doesn't give the numbers of course

Comment: I see. Hm, you might want to introduce the number as a function parameter and pass it (and increment it) from the main loop.

Comment: I added a code in the question based on your input @Thomas Lang. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, I meant changing the signature to `bool readNextSim(fstream &f, double parameters[], const int simulationIndex)` and printing the index alone instead of the 5-iteration loop inside that function.
In the main you then would do something like

`int simulationIndex = 0; while (readNexSim(stream, parameters, ++simulationIndex)) {  ...  }`

Comment: Okay got it. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Is there any particular reason preventing you from using classes to [organize your data](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tMtM1qiOM9hM2VhF)?